# How to figure out why the garbage collector is using 90% of my CPU?

Tags: java, debugging

I have a java program that starts getting laggy and using too much CPU after about 20-30 minutes of running, and continues to get worse as time goes on.

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 17.10 using the Open JRE 8_151. I confirmed that this bug also occurs on windows using Oracle JRE 8_131 (and i'm assuming 8_151).

I waited about 45 minutes until the program was using a lot of CPU (about 90%) and took the following actions to try to ID which thread in my program is being a hog:

```
ps aux 
#Visually confirm the process is using 90% and note ID -- 20316

top -p20316 
#confirm usage, in top it says 366.3%; 4-core processor so this makes sense

[while in top] press shift + H
# See four threads each using about 85%
  20318
  20319
  20320
  20321

# Convert those to hex
  20318 -> 0x4f5e
  20319 -> 0x4f5f
  20320 -> 0x4f60
  20321 -> 0x4f61

[Exit top]

jstack -l 20316 | less  
[press / and search for those hex thread ids]

# Get the following results: 
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff9f8020000 nid=0x4f5e runnable 
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff9f8021800 nid=0x4f5f runnable 
"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff9f8023800 nid=0x4f60 runnable 
"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff9f8025000 nid=0x4f61 runnable
```

So it's the garbage collector that's using up my CPU. That's not very helpful to me, because I don't know which thread is generating the objects that are being collected, or why it's consuming 85% of my processor power to garbage collect.

Where do I go from here to try to debug this issue? I can start disabling active running threads to see if the problem goes away, but given that it

1. Doesn't manifest every launch; and
2. Takes 20-30 minutes to start appearing

This may take a while, so I'm hoping for something a bit more clever, like what I tried above.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I never call System.gc() in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have a very large amount of long-lived objects. This is a deadly case for a garbage collector with generations. In this case try to use G1 GC.

Comment: I do. I have ~6000 small but long-lived objects. How do I specify using G1 GC?

Comment: use `-XX:+UseG1GC`

Comment: I'll give it a shot now and let you know how it goes. Really hoping to be able to accept your answer, thank you!

Comment: @JoshuaD Did it help. I'm having same trouble.

Comment: @Harshit Gupta Yea this helped a lot. I also used a process inspector on linux to see what threads were doing what.

Comment: @JoshuaD My CPU usage still creeps up to 100% and remain there until it is restarted.